# form numpy array from possible numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

### EDIT

I realized that I did not check my mwe very well and as such asked something of the wrong question.  The main problem is when the numpy array is passed in as a 2d array instead of 1d (or even when a python list is passed in as 1d instead of 2d).  So if we have

```
x = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
```

then obviously if you try to index this then you will get arrays out (if you use item you do not).  this same thing also applies to standard python lists.

Sorry about the confusion.

### Original

I am trying to form a new numpy array from something that may be a numpy array or may be a standard python list.

for example

```
import numpy as np

x = [2, 3, 1]

y = np.array([[0, -x[2], x[1]], [x[2], 0, -x[0]], [-x[1], x[0], 0]])
```

Now I would like to form a function such that I can make `y` easily.

```
def skew(vector):
    """
    this function returns a numpy array with the skew symmetric cross product matrix for vector.
    the skew symmetric cross product matrix is defined such that
    np.cross(a, b) = np.dot(skew(a), b)

    :param vector: An array like vector to create the skew symmetric cross product matrix for
    :return: A numpy array of the skew symmetric cross product vector
    """

    return np.array([[0, -vector[2], vector[1]], 
                     [vector[2], 0, -vector[0]], 
                     [-vector[1], vector[0], 0]])
```

This works great and I can now write (assuming the above function is included)

```
import numpy as np

x=[2, 3, 1]

y = skew(x)
```

However, I would also like to be able to call skew on existing 1d or 2d numpy arrays.  For instance

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([2, 3, 1])

y = skew(x)
```

Unfortunately, doing this returns a numpy array where the elements are also numpy arrays, not python floats as I would like them to be.

Is there an easy way to form a new numpy array like I have done from something that is either a python list or a numpy array and have the result be just a standard numpy array with floats in each element?

Now obviously one solution is to check to see if the input is a numpy array or not:

```
def skew(vector):
    """
    this function returns a numpy array with the skew symmetric cross product matrix for vector.
    the skew symmetric cross product matrix is defined such that
    np.cross(a, b) = np.dot(skew(a), b)

    :param vector: An array like vector to create the skew symmetric cross product matrix for
    :return: A numpy array of the skew symmetric cross product vector
    """
    if isinstance(vector, np.ndarray):
        return np.array([[0, -vector.item(2), vector.item(1)],
                         [vector.item(2), 0, -vector.item(0)],
                         [-vector.item(1), vector.item(0), 0]])
    else:
        return np.array([[0, -vector[2], vector[1]], 
                         [vector[2], 0, -vector[0]], 
                         [-vector[1], vector[0], 0]])
```

however, it gets very tedious having to write these instance checks all over the place.

Another solution would be to cast everything to an array first and then just use the array call

```
def skew(vector):
    """
    this function returns a numpy array with the skew symmetric cross product matrix for vector.
    the skew symmetric cross product matrix is defined such that
    np.cross(a, b) = np.dot(skew(a), b)

    :param vector: An array like vector to create the skew symmetric cross product matrix for
    :return: A numpy array of the skew symmetric cross product vector
    """

    vector = np.array(vector)

    return np.array([[0, -vector.item(2), vector.item(1)],
                     [vector.item(2), 0, -vector.item(0)],
                     [-vector.item(1), vector.item(0), 0]])
```

but I feel like this is inefficient as it requires creating a new copy of vector (in this case not a big deal since vector is small but this is just a simple example).

My question is, is there a different way to do this outside of what I've discussed or am I stuck using one of these methods?

Comment: Which numpy version are you using? For numpy 1.10.4 getting a single element from an array returns a scalar not a numpy array so your initial function works like you wanted.

Comment: I am using 1.10.4 @MSeifert, however I made a mistake in my question.  the main problem is that I am using 2d arrays to emulate column vectors.  I will fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are iterable. You can write in your skew function:

```
def skew(x):
    return np.array([[0, -x[2], x[1]],
                     [x[2], 0, -x[0]],
                     [-x[1], x[0], 0]])
x = [1,2,3]
y = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> skew(y)
array([[ 0, -3,  2],
       [ 3,  0, -1],
       [-2,  1,  0]])
>>> skew(x)
array([[ 0, -3,  2],
       [ 3,  0, -1],
       [-2,  1,  0]])
```

In any case your methods ended with 1st dimension elements being numpy arrays containing floats. You'll need in any case a call on the 2nd dimension to get the floats inside.

Regarding what you told me in the comments, you may add an if condition for 2d arrays:

```
def skew(x):
     if (isinstance(x,ndarray) and len(x.shape)>=2):
         return np.array([[0, -x[2][0], x[1][0]],
                          [x[2][0], 0, -x[0][0]],
                          [-x[1][0], x[0][0], 0]])
     else:
         return np.array([[0, -x[2], x[1]],
                          [x[2], 0, -x[0]],
                          [-x[1], x[0], 0]])
```

Comment: 1d arrays are easily iterable yes, however, 2d arrays are more complicated.  for instance, if `x=np.array([[1], [2], [3]])` then the above will not work (I generally keep my arrays as 2d to emulate column vectors).  sorry I was not clear in my question.  I will fix this

Comment: so I realize now that the best option is to use `x[1][0]` to index as this will always work for up to 2d arrays or lists without making a copy.  Can you update your answer to reflect this and I will then accept?

Comment: For numpy arrays you can check the lenght of 'vector.shape' method (2 for 2d arrays). For nested lists it may get a bit more tricky.

Comment: Thanks for making the update.  I would argue that you don't even need to go that far.  One could very easily write `np.array([[0, x[2][0], x[1][0]],...` regardless of whether `x` is 1d or 2d.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the last idea efficiently using [`numpy.asarray()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html):

```
vector = np.asarray(vector)
```

Then, if vector is already a NumPy array, no copying occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the first version of your function and convert the `numpy` array to `list`:

```
def skew(vector):

    if isinstance(vector, np.ndarray):
        vector = vector.tolist()

    return np.array([[0, -vector[2], vector[1]], 
                     [vector[2], 0, -vector[0]], 
                     [-vector[1], vector[0], 0]])

In [58]: skew([2, 3, 1])
Out[58]:
array([[ 0, -1,  3],
       [ 1,  0, -2],
       [-3,  2,  0]])

In [59]: skew(np.array([2, 3, 1]))
Out[59]:
array([[ 0, -1,  3],
       [ 1,  0, -2],
       [-3,  2,  0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an optimal solution but is a very easy one.
You can just convert the vector into list by default.

```
def skew(vector): 
    vector = list(vector)
    return np.array([[0, -vector[2], vector[1]], 
                     [vector[2], 0, -vector[0]], 
                     [-vector[1], vector[0], 0]])
```

Comment: do you know if list creates a copy if vector is already a list?  @John Zwinck below seemed to imply that asarray does not copy if the inside is already an array which would seem to be at least a little more efficient.

Comment: can you explain the added value of your question considering I gave this answer minutes before?

Comment: Are you referring to me @ColonelBeauvel?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen your answer I was already writing mine. However, mine is way less wordy and I am not sure that calling isinstance() would add anithing more...

Comment: `.tolist()` is better if the array may be 2d.

Answer (score 1):

In fewer lines

```
def skew(vector):
    return np.cross(np.eye(vector.size), vector.reshape(-1))
```

Comment: This is definitely a nice use of the theory, though its going to be relatively inefficient (of course, in all likelihood the efficiency difference is going to be negligible unless you are repeatedly using this function within some critical portion of the code, in which case the overhead of python is probably going to dominate anyway)

Comment: Indeed, I measure a 10x penalty over the direct construction method.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another option that removes conditionals to this old question.  This uses ravel (which does not make a copy) to "flatten" the array so its only 1D.

```
def skew(vector):
    """
    this function returns a numpy array with the skew symmetric cross product matrix for vector.
    the skew symmetric cross product matrix is defined such that
    np.cross(a, b) = np.dot(skew(a), b)

    :param vector: An array like vector to create the skew symmetric cross product matrix for
    :return: A numpy array of the skew symmetric cross product vector
    """

    vector = np.asarray(vector).ravel()

    return np.array([[0, -vector[2], vector[1]],
                     [vector[2], 0, -vector[0]],
                     [-vector[1], vector[0], 0]])
```

Additionally, for those interested, there is a form that handles multiple vectors at once (using multi-dimensional arrays) at https://github.com/nasa/giant/blob/main/giant/rotations.py#L1164